# is there an python method for solve this list index error?

Tags: python

> I have error that say: the list index out of range ?

```
equal_score = []

for i, j in enumerate(new_gd):    
    if i > len(new_gd):
        break
    if new_gd[i]['score'] == new_gd[i+1]['score']:
        equal_score.append(new_gd[i])
        equal_score.append(new_gd[i+1])'
```

Comment: The last index in the loop is `i`, but you try to access `new_gd[i+1]`. The last index of `new_gd` is at `len(new_gd) - 1` so your `if` statement should be `if i >= len(new_gd) - 1:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you refer to the index `i+1` you should do `if i+1 >= len(new_gd): break` so you make sure `i+1` exists.